# wrong Chartset when using pdo class

Tags: php, pdo

In my app, I use this class to connect database: https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class

```
it has: PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
my php has: header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
my html has:  <meta charset="utf-8" />
my database charset is: utf8-general-ci   
my table  charset is: utf8-general-ci  
my field charset is:  varchar(1024) utf8_general_ci
```

When I insert chinese via phpadmin, it shows good, but when I insert data via pdo, it show è¿æ¯ä»ä¹å

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the solution.

https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class/blob/master/Db.class.php

lines 142

change `utf8_encode($value);`  to `$value;`